# How to calculate Current/Longest Streak of income vs Goal in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a list of People, tracking the number of units sold per month. They have their goals listed in the sheet, so each month has 2 columns ("units sold" and "vs goal" which is calculated `units sold - goal`). I want to calculate the current streak, counting meeting their goal or exceeding it as a win and not meeting as a loss, and their longest win streak.

Sheet included with manually entering what the values should be for current and longest streak. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YE8EzBKIeHetKSXP6J7KiDfBkiZDv9dSurUDLHmLS0U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I did, it is in the linked sheet like I said

Comment: No, because John A "lost" in January 2020, but "won" in December 2019 since he got 1100 when his goal was 1000, winning by 100.

Comment: So I just want the current streak, so if he won this month and lost last month, or vice versa, nothing else that came before that matters. Just the number of consecutive months before this month that have the same result as the current month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A3:A="",,MMULT(IF((E2:Z2="sold"), 
 IF(E3:Z>=B3:B, 1, 0), 0), SIGN(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(E:Z)))^0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Perfect, that is exactly what I am looking for for longest Win Streak! Any tips for current win or loss streak?